# AttributeError at /accounts/register/ 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, attributes

I'm getting

> AttributeError at /accounts/register/
>
> 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

I could have a spelling mistake in some of my files.

### urls.py

(In project)

```
"""QuestionTime URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from django_registration.backends.one_step.views import RegistrationView

from users.forms import CustomUserForm

# https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.2/activation-workflow.html

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path("accounts/register/", RegistrationView.as_view(
         form_class="CustomUserForm",
         success_url="/",
         ), name="django_registration_register"),

    path("accounts/", include("django_registration.backends.one_step.urls")),

    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),

    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls")),

    path("api/rest-auth/", include("rest_auth.urls")),

    path("api/rest-auth/registration/", include("rest_auth.registration.urls")),
]
```

### forms.py

(in app)

```
from django_registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from users.models import CustomUser


class CustomUserForm(RegistrationForm):

    class Meta(RegistrationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
```

`django_registration.forms` and `django_registration.backends.one_step.views` gets highlighted yellow in VSCODE

Comment: `form_class="CustomUserForm"` remove those quotes from there, so it should be `form_class=CustomUserForm`...

Comment:  It's the solution.